DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-12_4_1'. Firebase Not Initialized
Hey I am having this issue from yesterday. I have the latest Firebase versions installed from their website. I am only using Firebase Authentication for now. Build process is successful but I am getting the following error in an Android build. I have already tried re-importing the SDKs, deleting library folder reopening project etc.
I have the google-services file inside my Assets/ folder and correct google-services-desktop.json is generated. I have Firebase Analytics disabled.

Failed to initialize Firebase SDK since google-services.json was not applied to your gradle.


Error Unity DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-12_4_1'. Tried the load the following dynamic libraries: Unable to load dynamic library 'FirebaseCppApp-12_4_1' because of 'Failed to open the requested dynamic library (0x06000000) dlerror() = dlopen failed: library "FirebaseCppApp-12_4_1" not found

Unity Version : 2022.3.45f1
Firebase Version : 12.4.1
I am trying to implement Google Sign In using Firebase. I am following the very basic steps but still this issue.

Have a look at the import setting of the plugin (dll). These are stored at .meta files and needs to be imported for your platform.

What do you exactly mean by that?

Hello I have managed to fix this issue. There were a few files named .srcaar in google-sign-in-support whose extension needed to be changed to .aar.
Outside the google-support folder there is a .xml file. Modify the extension values and everything started working well and good.
